# Build error with the duplicates (Apache HttpClient) - Android

Tags: android, apache, httpclient

I want to use the Twilio in my application. for that the i added the dependency

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

But the problem, when i was trying to build there is a build error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/concurrent/Cancellable.class
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    //    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.twillosample"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:5.10.0'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    //    compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
    //        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android'
    //    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: i tried many times, Can you please help how to exclude the dependecies

Comment: @JagadeshSeeram I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is the duplicate entry of `org.apache.httpcomponents`, so that Catch one possible compilation that might include `org.apache.httpcomponents` and exclude it. Let's take an example of `ews-java-api`.

Suppose you may have two compilation in your `build.gradle` like,

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.microsoft.ews-java-api:ews-java-api:2.0'
```

Then you have to exclude `org.apache.httpcomponents` from `com.microsoft.ews-java-api:ews-java-api:2.0` compilation like,

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile ('com.microsoft.ews-java-api:ews-java-api:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

**NOTE :** It's only an example, Refer [this discussion](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/506) as well,

Comment: I added the exclude in my gradle

Comment: Have you tried that in both compilation separately ?

Comment: Even when i add the 'httpclient' in the gradle. There is an exception  - NoClassDefFound - PoolingClientConnectionManager

Comment: Are you sure you've added that exclude only in `compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:5.10.0'`

Comment: Ya... exclude module: 'httpcore'

Comment: Why not `exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117582/discussion-between-jagadesh-seeram-and-shree-krishna).

Comment: Hey after excluding group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' I'm getting the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig; Could someone please help? Thanks